# connecting mobile application with firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i connected my existing project to firebase, but after connecting when i run the code i get the following problem. i use flutter and dart in this application. i am new in firebase please help me solving the error.
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX2185 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15:.
> Required by:
> project :

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
E/AndroidRuntime(21390): FATAL EXCEPTION: EnCodeFileHandlerThread
E/AndroidRuntime(21390): Process: com.oppo.lfeh, PID: 21390
E/AndroidRuntime(21390): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:777)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:514)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:457)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:254)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1424)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at com.oppo.lfeh.core.OppoFileEncodeHelper.getFileList(OppoFileEncodeHelper.java:627)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at com.oppo.lfeh.core.OppoFileEncodeHelper.removeTempFileAndKeepDirSmall(OppoFileEncodeHelper.java:1457)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at com.oppo.lfeh.core.OppoFileEncodeHelper.startScanAndEncodeFileReady(OppoFileEncodeHelper.java:1741)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at com.oppo.lfeh.core.OppoFileEncodeHelper.access$1200(OppoFileEncodeHelper.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at com.oppo.lfeh.core.OppoFileEncodeHelper$EnCodeFileHandler.handleMessage(OppoFileEncodeHelper.java:2161)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(21390):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i have tried disconnecting the project from firebase and run it to see whether i could get the same problem but it did not appear, i have also tried adding an authentication into the firebase but it did not work. the error persists.